# Best way to update react 'dirty' state within component?

Tags: reactjs

If I have a react component that will pop up a "Are you sure" confirm modal if the state is dirty, what is the most convenient way to mark dirty? I have a basic local array state of objects that can have their values changed, and items deleted/added. Right now I have a setState({dirty: true}) in valuesChanged(), addItem(), deleteItem(), toggleSwitch(), etc. I know there is a less redundant way to accomplish this, perhaps comparing state in a component life cycle. I am just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React 17.0 will be removing `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle hook (and a couple of others) and will begin the deprecation process in React 16.3. See [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12152) for some more information. There's a blog post coming too.

So with that said, you could do something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    //add whatever comparison logic you need here
    if(this.state.someValue !== prevState.someValue && !this.state.dirty) {
        this.setState({ dirty: true });
    }

    //optionally you could also reset dirty here if you also
    //persisted the original values and the user undid their
    //changes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@justin, you can use `componentWillReceiveProps` life-cycle method:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.dirty !== this.props.dirty) {
       ***do something here****
      }
  }
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class

Comment: I want to be able to mark the state dirty in this lifecycle though, and input changes are not firing componentsWillReceiveProps.